# Azure Pipelines GitHub App - Installing on-premise?

Tags: azure-devops, self-hosting, github-enterprise

What is the best way to go about adding Status Checks from Azure DevOps in a self-hosted scenario using a private GitHub Enterprise instance (not accessible externally).

Presently our setup is self-hosted with the agent installed on our build servers.  We have a custom hook that tells Azure Pipelines to start a build however we aren't sure the best way to deal with the status checks.  It would be preferable to not have each build pipeline have to make custom REST calls for the status checks rather have some means to register the status check between systems.

Has anyone configured for this scenario before?

Thanks!